# Angular 17 server-side rendering: how to access HTTP headers?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I was following [these instructions](https://dev.to/deekshithrajbasa/angular-server-side-rendering-ssr-the-browser-is-not-the-server-30a5) to access the HTTP headers on the server side.

But those instructions are for `@nguniversal`.

How does this change for `@angular/ssr`?

```
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens'

constructor(
   @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request,
   // ...
) {
  this.request.headers['...']
  // ...
}
```

I find a lot of outdated (pre-17) documentation and discussions of `TransferState` - but my issue is about how to get the appropriate data depending on the request, not how to transfer it.

Others have the same problem (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/18hht71/request_headers_not_working_in_angular_17_ssr/)), but I could not find anyone having a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should now create them yourself :

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
export const RESPONSE = new InjectionToken<Response>('RESPONSE');
```

Just so you know, this is what the migration schematics does when migrating from v16 to v17.

Also, please note that ATM if you use the application builder, the vite dev-server does not use Express or the config you have in `server.ts`. See the [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/26175) on the Angular CLI repo.

Comment: That doesn't work, the request and response are always `null`.